# Write String to text file in Planner

Tags: java, string, file, text

** I am a beginner in Java and I'm making a planner and I need to write the string of the date, time, name, and description of their event and then find it later and display information about their event. How do I write to a text file and then find it later? Thanks!**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Test {

    /**
     * @throws IOException 
     * @param args
     * @throws 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner ( System.in );
        String choice;
        String password = null;
        String time = null, name = null, dateview = null, dateedit, description = null, dateadd = null;
        FileWriter ostream;


        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome To The Pocket Planner!");
        System.out.println("");
        password = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please Enter Your Password");
        while (!password.toUpperCase().equals("PASSWORD"))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Try Again", "Incorrect Password", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            password = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please Enter Your Password");
        }

        {
            do{
                do{
                    do{

                        choice = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Type \"View\" To View Your Schedule" + "\n" + "Type \"Edit\" To Edit Your Schedule" + "\n" + "Type \"Add\" To Add To Your Schedule");

                        if (choice.equals("View")){
                            dateview = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the date you want to view in this format: MM/DD/YY");
                            while(dateadd != null){
                                FileInputStream istream = new FileInputStream("filename.txt");
                                DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(istream);
                                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));String strLine;
                                dateadd = br.readLine();
                            if(dateadd.equalsIgnoreCase(dateview)){
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, (time + ":" + "\n" + name + " -" + " " + description));
                            }
                            else 
                            {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Try Again", "Event Not Found", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                            }
                            }
                        }
                        else if (choice.equals("Edit")){
                            dateedit = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the date you want to edit in this format: MM/DD/YY");
                        }
                        else if (choice.equals("Add")) {
                            name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the name of the event you want to add.");
                            dateadd = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the date you want to add in this format: MM/DD/YY");
                            time = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the time of your event");
                            description = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the description of your event");

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Try Again", "Invalid Entry", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);   
                        }
                    }while(!choice.toUpperCase().equals("Edit"));
                }while(!choice.toUpperCase().equals("View"));
            }while(!choice.toUpperCase().equals("Add"));

        }





    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html) will help a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could concatenate the date, time, name etc strings with a delimiter such as $$$ (this delimiter should not appear in the name, so use one accordingly).

Then

```
File file = new File("textfile.txt");
// This is the file in which you want to write all planner entries
output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
output.write(text);
```

To read, open the file like so

```
FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("textfile.txt");
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
String strLine;

while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   { // Until file has content, keep reading
String[] temp;
temp = strLine.split("$$$");

//using string.split() with the delimiter to get back all the sub-strings.

}
```

Comment: Please don't use DataInputStream if you want to read text, its more confusing than useful.

Answer (score 1):

Long term, I'd suggest taking a look at Java's XML capabilities

Take a look at

- http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/java-xml-tutorials/
- http://java.sun.com/xml/tutorial_intro.html

In the mean time, you might like to look over http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/